# ssh to a remote server with environment variables

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, environment-variables

When I ssh to a remote server via: `ssh root@xxx`, the `~/.bashrc` file is automatically applied. Then `env` returns:

```bsh
XDG_SESSION_ID=394867
NVM_CD_FLAGS=
TERM=xterm-256color
SHELL=/bin/bash
HISTSIZE=3000
DERBY_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db
SSH_CLIENT=220.248.92.74 47797 22
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/0
NVM_DIR=/root/.nvm
USER=root
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
MAIL=/var/mail/root
PATH=/root/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.2/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin
PWD=/root
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
SHLVL=1
HOME=/root
LOGNAME=root
J2SDKDIR=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
SSH_CONNECTION=220.248.92.74 47797 172.17.0.4 22
LC_CTYPE=zh_CN.UTF-8
NVM_BIN=/root/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.2/bin
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
PROMPT_COMMAND=history -a;
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/0
J2REDIR=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
HISTTIMEFORMAT=%F %T
_=/usr/bin/env
```

But if I ssh to the server with command `ssh root@xxx "env"`, the `~/.bashrc` file is not applied. The `env` returns:

```bsh
XDG_SESSION_ID=394872
SHELL=/bin/bash
SSH_CLIENT=220.248.92.74 22294 22
USER=root
MAIL=/var/mail/root
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
PWD=/root
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
SHLVL=1
HOME=/root
LOGNAME=root
SSH_CONNECTION=220.248.92.74 22294 172.17.0.4 22
LC_CTYPE=zh_CN.UTF-8
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/0
_=/usr/bin/env
```

Even if I `ssh root@xxx "source ~/.bashrc; env;"` does not make any difference. I wonder why `.bashrc` file cannot be applied in the last two senarios?

Comment: "I wonder why .bashrc file cannot be applied..." Please [edit] your question to include the contents of this .bashrc file (and any other startup files which it references). You should also include the output of running "env" after sourcing the file.

Comment: Try `ssh -tt root@xxx env`

Answer (score 1):

By default, only interactive shells source `~/.bashrc`, which is likely why you are not getting any environment variables (or aliases) you have defined in your `~/.bashrc`.

As for your example where you `ssh root@xxx "source .bashrc; env;"`, it may be that your `.bashrc` is checking if the shell is interactive and exiting early.

For the record, important bit from the `bash(1)` man page:

> When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, bash reads and executes commands from ~/.bashrc, if that file exists. This may be inhibited by using the --norc option. The --rcfile file option will force bash to read and execute commands from file instead of ~/.bashrc.

Comment: This is actually a [compile-time option](https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/unix/BashDetectRemoteInvocation) and the behavior might differ between distributions. The default is off, but OP might be used to Debian enabling it.